# Error with Dynamic SQL Data Transfer: Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for subtract operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, dynamic-sql, datetime-conversion

I need to transfer data between tables in a database. The issue is that the old table uses a 6-character format (YYMMDD) for dates in the "RecordDate" column, whereas the new target table has this column defined as datetime.

When attempting to move the data using CONVERT(DATETIME, RecordDate), I encounter the following error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

To address this, I employed a CASE WHEN structure, and the data conversion was successful. Here is the working query:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
        WHEN ISDATE('20' + SUBSTRING(RecordDate, 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RecordDate, 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RecordDate, 5, 2)) = 1 
        THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '20' + SUBSTRING(RecordDate, 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RecordDate, 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RecordDate, 5, 2))
        ELSE NULL 
        END AS RecordDate

FROM 
    sourceTable;
```

However, when integrating this into a dynamic query using sp_executesql, I encounter the error: "Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for subtract operator." This is due to the usage of the CASE statement in the dynamic query.
Here's the relevant dynamic query section:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = '
INSERT INTO targetTable 
(RecordDate, ...other columns...)
SELECT
    (CASE 
        WHEN ISDATE(''20'' + SUBSTRING(RecordDate, 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RecordDate, 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RecordDate, 5, 2)) = 1 
        THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, ''20'' + SUBSTRING(RecordDate, 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RecordDate, 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RecordDate, 5, 2))
        ELSE NULL 
    END) AS RecordDate,
    ...other columns...
FROM  sourceTable
';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

However, the usage of CASE in the dynamic query triggers the error. How can I resolve this issue and successfully execute the dynamic query for data transfer?

Comment: you need to escape all `'` quotes into two quotes `''` inside the dynamic sql string. If you add `PRINT(@sql)` befor executing, you should see where it goes wrong

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; `'...1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(...'` means the string `''...1, 2) + '` *minus* the string `' + SUBSTRING(...'` and that really doesn't make any sense. Though, from the SQL you've shown us, I can't see why you need to use a deferred statement at all.

Comment: That was already the problem, I missed it, thank you

Comment: @siggemannen, the problem is occuring at assignment, so the `PRINT` would never be reached.

Comment: Why is dynamic SQL used *at all*? The question just concatenates hard-coded strings. You don't even need all those substring operations, just `cast('20'+RecordDate as date)` is enough. The `YYYYMMDD` is an unambiguous format. If you expect bad data use `TRY_CAST`.

Comment: I suspect this is a [XY problem](//xyproblem.info) and the *real* problem is that your column `RecordDate` is infact *not* a date (and time) value but a string based value; fix the design and store dates (and time) values in a date (and time) data type.

Comment: On the other hand, if you get an out of range error it means the column doesn't contain what you expected. Neither `date` nor `datetime` have an upper limit of 2099. That means the field contains different values, perhaps even in the `YYYYMMDD` format already

Comment: This means that you can't copy the data at all. You have to *fix* the data first, and find what that column actually contains. Otherwise you may end up mangling *good* dates because an incorrect assumption was made

Comment: Never mind that just appending `20` introduces the Y2K bug all over again. Who says that `20` is 1920 instead of 2020 for example? Or vice versa? The big IT news before the COVID-19 lockdowns were the [LLoyd's](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/) and the UK's [DVLA crashes](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/13/y2k_dvla/) because of exactly that kind of assumption. It would be safer to use `TRY_CONVERT` with the 12 style than randomly assume a century

Comment: [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) documentation is your friend. And don't forget `TRY_CAST()` and `TRY_CONVERT()` exist for those occasions when your data isn't quite as your expect - such as when it might contain empty strings or other randomness.